# ubuntu can't find serial port

Tags: 18.04, usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, serial-port, arduino

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS downloaded from Microsoft store and Arduino IDE. I'm trying to use ESP32 in Ubuntu, but Ubuntu can't find the serial port.

In Arduino, `Tools` > `Port` is greyed out.
In Windows, I can see `ESP32(COM7)` and it works.

`lsusb` outputs nothing.
`dmesg` only outputs `[0.009121]  Microsoft 4.4.0-17763.379-Microsoft 4.4.35`.

I tried:

- kernel update
- add the user to dialout
- install cp210x driver

Comment: Low level I/O stuff that needs kernel functionality do generally not work with WSL. Think your serial ports belongs to this category.

Answer (score 3):

another possible issue is the cable.

according to this issue some people are having, it is possible the cable does not support data transfer

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/902

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue. but finally connected.

ESP32 in ubuntu don't connect default

sudo apt-get install git wget libncurses-dev flex bison gperf python python-pip python-setuptools python-serial python-click python-cryptography python-future python-pyparsing python-pyelftools cmake ninja-build ccache libffi-dev libssl-dev

after this connect /dev/ttyUSB0 worked :)